# When training NER with BIO chunks what would be the most suitable approach in following case?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

In my case I want to tag following under DISEASE and SYMPTOM tags

*Eg : Osgood-Schlatter disease is a painful inflammation of the upper portion of the tibia.*

where I have successfully trained as `Osgood-Schlatter/b-disease disease/i-disease` (I have used BIO NER tag approach)

However I am not sure whether is it correct to tag remaining part **"painful inflammation of the upper portion of the tibia"** as Symptom itself.

as `painful/b-symptom  inflammation/i-symptom of/i-symptom the/i-symptom upper/i-symptom portion/i-symptom of/i-symptom the/i-symptom tibia/i-symptom`

I would like any opinion whether to use my current approach or should I follow POS tag based parsing approach or any other suitable approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the similar use case in financial domain, i have got fairly good results with this approach.
But I had also used POS tags and distsim approach to train the model.
That way you provide more features to learn from.